# Ethereum light client roadmap?

Tags: clients, light-clients, android

The [Ethereum roadmap](https://blog.ethereum.org/2015/03/03/ethereum-launch-process/) makes no mention about when to expect a [light client](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/Light-client-protocol). Anyone has any insights on when we could expect to see a light client that could efficiently run on, say, an Android device?

Comment: Roadmaps are moving targets and not a good fit for StackExchange. It's better to ask on another site like the [Ethereum reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/ethereum).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The light client ([LES](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/Light-client-protocol)) is currently only being developed in the [Go Ethereum](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum) codebase and is currently rounding off the first of two phases.

The first phase consists of the following high level components:

- [•] Validating header
- [•] Validating state information
- [•] Querying state information (accounts, code, nonces, etc.)
- [•] Validating receipts
- [ ] Sending transactions

The first phase is partially under review (ticked tasks) and Zsolt is working on implementing the sending of transactions. This requires a bit of work because of accounting (nonces in particular, inclusion checks, etc.). This phase will roughly end in Two Wooks™ ;-)

The second phase will consist of the following tasks and isn't being worked on yet:

- Bloom filter inspection, validation and filtering
- Log filtering
- Log validation

The second phase will make the LES "feature complete" and will bring an end to the 0.1 LES PoC.

Comment: I'd like to add [Zsolt's talk from DevCon1](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KoEqh99U5QI)

Comment: [Zsolt did it](https://twitter.com/BobSummerwill/status/691859663726473216). :-)

Answer (score 2):

There are ongoing efforts to integrate a light client into the go Ethereum client. More information are available in the corresponding [pull request](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/pull/2102).